# AlpineJs x-data variable not updated after wire:model

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js

On a back-end I'm making, I have different fiches on a product detail. The can add as many fiches as they want but only one of them can be the "default" fiche. A toggle can make the selected fiche the default and the other fiches must be set as "non default".

Everything works great, only the x-data variable isn't updated so the toggle still displays as true while it should display as false.

A toggle is modeled with wire:model on an item in an array. I have a Livewire function, a lifecycle hook, that checks when this value is update to change all the other "default" values to false.

As you can see in the screenshots, with debugging values, the x-data value changes but the x-text is still active and thus not updated.

What am I missing here?

[Livewire debug + load toggle component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukapG.png)

[Toggle component with debug info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDhDp.png)

[End result: fiche "To buy" was the default at first but this is the result when setting the "To buy" fiche as "non default" so the fiche "rent" is set to active through a livewire lifecycle hook. As you can see, the livewire debug info is "1" and the Alpine "toggled" value is also set to "1" but the "toggle" value is still "0" (as it was when the page was loaded).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsjQO.png)

[The generated HTML code also shows the x-data variable "toggle" as "1", which is correct but the x-text "toggle" is "0", what supposed to be "1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmbTQ.png)

I tried different approaches but always ended in this same situation.

Bottom line: why is x-text not updated, while the other variables are?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, but post the code instead. Screenshots make it hard to follow, and more importantly, disallow people from copying to try and reproduce your situation.